# Apollo-cli instead of Apollo-codegen is resulting of a wrong output?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm working on Android Studio with apollo to use GraphQL.

I saw that apollo-codegen has been update as Apollo-cli.
Before the command was

> apollo-codegen download-schema https://api.github.com/graphql

And it has been update to

> apollo schema:download --endpoint=https://api.github.com/graphql

But when i check the two output they are totally different.
When i update the new schema into my Android Studio i also get an error.

How did you manage it ? What do i do wrong ? Thanks by advance for the helps :)

Comment: did you find answer?

Comment: Yep, the command has been update and the space has been removed, it worked now :)

Comment: maybe do you know some tutorial with this last updates?

Comment: i added scheme. But after create a some FeedQuery.graphql  file with query and compile, then it not generate some kotlin/java classes. Where i could make a mistake?

Comment: where to put package-lock?

Comment: Everything is explaning here -> https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling

Comment: Check this also -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BZjPSUZjak&list=PLqbJh0bQeVRoyrlClNSFe6sIZSjFB5s-e
The command are wrong but you can follow the step with the right command, comme back if it's still not fixed :)

Comment: the same! I did all this things, but it not work. I added a scheme, but i putted it in directory like in video, but i get this error: Couldn't find schema files for the variant Debug. Please ensure a valid schema.json exists under the varian't source sets

Comment: This error occurred when i adding a simple query to directory with scheme. And this query is working, i checked

Comment: Wait, i think i found a solution..

Comment: Yes, i found a solution! i was used sudo to install node, and other stuff, that's why project couldn't see my schema.json. I just reinstall all this without sudo command. TY, bro!

Comment: Happy to see that you find your solution :) I got stuck by this same problem before also :p